# ASP.NET: Form Authentication is not working with IE8

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms, internet-explorer-8

I just found out that my site authentication is not working in IE8. It works in FF, Chrome, Opera but not in IE8. I've deleted all the cookies and temporary files but no change. After a short research I found out that there is some problems with the cookies with IE8.

Look at this http://www.reachfarther.com/persistent_cookies_fail_in_ie8.html

Here is my web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" domain="ivan_g" name=".MY_WEB_AUTH_COOKIE" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10" protection="All"></forms>
    </authentication>

    <httpCookies domain="ivan_g" />
```

I want to run the site from my PC at the office so my domain is ivan_g I think. This is the Url:

http://ivan_g/devsite/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdevsite%2fDefault.aspx

Can u help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Your url is invalid because it contains an underscore which is an invalid hostname character.

The following will work:

http://ivang/devsite/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdevsite%2fDefault.aspx